# How to run `microsoftTeams.media.scanBarCode` API on load of the application

Tags: angular, microsoft-teams

I am invoking an URL from my extension application inside MS Teams.

The URL is nothing but an angular application.

At the start of the application, I want o run this certain API `microsoftTeams.media.scanBarCode`.

I am able to run the API on the click event but when I am running on `OnInit` nothing happens.

**Angular Code:**

```
    config: microsoftTeams.media.BarCodeConfig = {
        timeOutIntervalInSec: 30,
    };

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.media.scanBarCode((error: microsoftTeams.SdkError, decodedText: string) => {
            if (error) {
                if (error.message) {
                    console.log(' ErrorCode: ' + error.errorCode + error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log(' ErrorCode: ' + error.errorCode);
                }
                this.message = error;
            } else if (decodedText) {
                microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(decodedText);
            }
        }, this.config);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please check console errors? What Microsoft Teams SDK version are you using?

Comment: I am using version `"@microsoft/teams-js": "^1.9.0",` also, with the error I am getting is 9000

Comment: I've. update the version to `1.10.0` still same

Comment: On which platform you are facing this issue?

Comment: I am running this on mobile devices (iPhone) - but here is the thing the API works fine on button click but I am interested on the initialisation of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same when tried with your code. My guess was that something is not getting initialized and prior to that scanBarCode is getting called.
So I did try adding the code in `microsoftTeams.initialize();` callback.

```
microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
  const config: microsoftTeams.media.BarCodeConfig = {
    timeOutIntervalInSec: 30
  };

  // Method that enables the user to scan different types of barcode, and returns the result as a string.  
  microsoftTeams.media.scanBarCode((error: microsoftTeams.SdkError, decodedText: string) => {
    // If there's any error, an alert shows the error message/code
    if (error) {
      if (error.message) {
        alert(" ErrorCode: " + error.errorCode + error.message);
      } else {
        alert(" ErrorCode: " + error.errorCode);
      }
    } else if (decodedText) {
      setBarCodeValue(decodedText);
    }
  }, config);
});
```

It worked for me. Please check if this resolve your issue as well.

Comment: worked really well!, thanks